# How to take the value of input and put it in confirmation form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input where you can insert a number and press submit then a confirmation form appears and asks you `Are sure...nr selected is:` and I want it to show me the number that I inserted.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="amount" >
<div id="dataConfirm" class="getnumber" data-title="Nr. selected is:" data-content="MY NUMBER" ></div>
```

```js
$("#dataConfirm").confirm();
```

So in `data-content`, where is `MY NUMBER`? I want to display the input number. I'm using jquery-confirm plugin v2.5.1.

Comment: Do you want to set input value in `data-content`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$.confirm`.

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function() {
  var val = $('#amount').val();
  $.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: 'Are sure...nr selected is:' + val,
    confirm: function() {
      $('#dataConfirm').data('content', val);
      console.log($('#dataConfirm').data('content'));
    },
    cancel: function() {

    }
  });
})
```

```js
$('#myform').on('submit', function() {
  var val = $('#amount').val();
  $.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: 'Are sure...nr selected is:' + val,
    confirm: function() {
      $('#dataConfirm').data('content', val);
      console.log($('#dataConfirm').data('content'));
    },
    cancel: function() {

    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/2.5.1/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/2.5.1/jquery-confirm.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="amount">
</form>
<div id="dataConfirm" class="getnumber" data-title="Nr. selected is:" data-content="MY NUMBER"></div>
```

Comment: Very complete answer.

Comment: Thx ! u made my day

Answer (score 0):

You have to populate *content* first. Using:

```
$.confirm({
    content:    <- set desired value here
```

jquery-confirm is for View only, *content* will not populate itself.

If it helps, to retrieve the value you can use:

```
document.getElementById('dataConfirm'); //returns a HTML DOM Object
```

or

```
var content = $('#dataConfirm');  //returns a jQuery Object
```